# Azure Monitor Alert reported Memory Working Set Percentage as AKS node memory reserved 101 percent. How to fix?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Azure Monitor Alert reported Memory Working Set Percentage as my AKS node memory reserved 101 percent (4.5 GB reserved out of 4.4 GB allocated). How to fix? I have a node pool which has 40 pods in running state and enabled autoscaling to minimum 1 and maximum 5 nodes. How should I free up the memory or will autoscale?

```
Kubernetes version: 1.25.11

NAME                               CPU(cores)  CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
aks-agentpool-XXXXXX-vmss000000     229m         12%    4590Mi          101%
```

Metric alert condition type: SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria

Any advise please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the article, [About the cluster autoscaler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler#about-the-cluster-autoscaler) The cluster autoscaler watches for pods that can't be scheduled on nodes because of resource constraints.